# How to install RMySQL package on Windows 7

Tags: mysql, r, package, rmysql

I would like to install RMySQL package on my computer running on Windows 7. On the package website, http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/index.html , it seems that the Windows package version doesn't exist... I try to understand the ReadMe, but I couldn't.

Does someone could tell me how to install properly this package ?

I tried the following code

```
install.packages('RMySQL', type='source')
```

and I get the following message :

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RMySQL’ is not available (for R version 3.0.0)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/XXXXX/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RMySQL_0.9-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 165363 bytes (161 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 161 Kb

* installing *source* package 'RMySQL' ...
** package 'RMySQL' correctement décompressé et sommes MD5 vérifiées
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'RMySQL'
* removing 'C:/Users/XXXXX/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/RMySQL'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\R\win-library\3.0" C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpo9RLF3/downloaded_packages/RMySQL_0.9-3.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RMySQL’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpo9RLF3\downloaded_packages’
```

And nothing appears in the Packages windows in RStudio... 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at `RODBC` package as a work around.

Comment: How do I connect to MYSQL Server using RODBC?

Answer (score 0):

From that readme file:

> Packages related to many database system must be linked to the exact 
>   version of the database system the user has installed, hence it does 
>   not make sense to provide binaries for packages   RMySQL, ROracle,
>   ROracleUI, TSMySQL, dbConnect although it is possible to install such
>   packages from sources by  install.packages('packagename',
>   type='source') after reading the manual 'R Installation and
>   Administration'.